Как исправить в VS2008 приложение, случайную иконку .ico?

Будто бы что-то там сползнает, смещается, и у 1-го единственного прилоржении, в панели задач, каждый раз новую иконку показывает (даже если ярлыки ему выставляют иконку правильную). Иконки анамально различаются даже в Form1 и NotiFyIcon1. "в реестре никаких упоминаний для этого приложения при поиске ФайлаИмя.exe, только MUICache".

Предсказуемость случаености: (1) Показывает иконку последнюю которая была показана на это приложение. Например если выставить ярлыком иконку. То на самом приложении, даже стрелка ярлыка останется.
(2) Кратчен говоря, в DOS-воской обстановке Windows, известна важность уникальности имени файла. У приложения несанкицонированные мусорные иконки, вместо установленной, и это зависит только от имени приложения. Приложению досталось такое имя на которое "обраушается проблема", ниче нерешает кроме переименовывания проекта. "аномалии протравили".

Помогает
(1) Исключить .icon: 1: с 2-я размерами сразу; 2 палитра <16 цветов



Ничего непонятно.
